# MVP view/presenter registration

Tags: c#, winforms, autofac

I'm working on an MVP based GUI architecture for a WinForms application and would like to use Autofac to keep track of the different parts. I keep running into circular component dependencies and would appreciate a gentle push in the right direction.

The architecture is based on [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/lennykean/archive/2012/02/21/winforms-and-mvp-making-a-testable-application.aspx) post where the View is as passive as i gets. The View holds no reference to the Presenter. The View is passed to the Presenter on construction. So in the non-DI world you would start your program with:

```
var MainView = new MainView();
var mainPresenter = new MainPresenter(mainView, new DataRepository());
Application.Run(mainView);
```

Ok, so the Presenter needs to know about the View instance to do its job. How can I express that in the registration code? This is what I've tried:

```
builder.RegisterType<MainPresenter>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MainView>().As<IMainView>().PropertiesAutowired().SingleInstance();
```

And then in Program.cs:

```
var mainPresenter = Container.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
Application.Run(Container.Resolve<IMainView>() as MainView);
```

But this way I need to remember to create the Presenter instance. However I would like to express in the registration that if I request a IMainView instance the MainPresenter should be kicked into action. But how....

Any hints, mockery or derisive laughter are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to solve it this way: Register the presenter and view without property injection since you say the view needs no reference to the presenter, and constructor injection is considered best practice in Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterType<MainPresenter>().SingleInstance();
builder.RegisterType<MainView>().As<IMainView>();
```

Inject the view into the presenter through constructor and publish it as a readonly property:

```
public class MainPresenter
{
  // Private variables

  private readonly IMainView _view;

  // Constructor

  public MainPresenter(IMainView view)
  {
    _view = view;
  }

  // Properties

  public IMainView View
  {
    get { return _view; }
  }
}
```

Then you fire up the application through a single resolve:

```
var mainPresenter = Container.Resolve<MainPresenter>();
Application.Run(mainPresenter.View as Form);
```

Finally, if you find later on that you need a reference from the view to the presenter, I think you would have to use property-injection on the view to avoid circular reference exceptions. Then you can register the view like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<MainView>().As<IMainView>().PropertiesAutowired(PropertyWiringFlags.AllowCircularDependencies);
```

and supply the view with a read/write property that will be set by Autofac

```
public MainPresenter Presenter { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I like the idea about showing the 'mainPresenter.View'. I have been staring myself blind on resolving both View and Presenter from the container.